# Why sfcc use isml instead of html?

Tags: demandware, salesforce-commerce-cloud

Why can't sfcc use html directly instead of isml. One reason I can see is to display dynamic content. But I wanted to know is there any other specific reason for it

Answer (score 0):

using isml for templating sfcc allows the developer to do the following:

- determine how B2C Commerce embeds live data into a page
- determine how to format this data together with the regular HTML code

one more thing, is the huge utility of tags, helpers and commands that allows the developer to deal with different data models and views